# I am not able to re-install NetBeans 15. During installation Critical error occurs

Tags: java, netbeans

I was using NetBeans IDE quite fine, I was able to create new projects and java programs, then errors began to appear after trying to add a JAR file path, also I was not able to create new projects. So, I uninstalled NetBeans 15 and tried to re-install it but a critical error showns, which is shown in the image.[Critical Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4xxi.png)

I  tried to install other previous versions of NetBeans but same error is showing. Tried re-installing JDK (version 8.0.2020.08) but still problem persists when installing NetBeans. Please help:)

Comment: This site might help you, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-solve-an-illegalargumentexception-in-java

Comment: Website https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb15/ states "The Apache NetBeans 15 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17."

Comment: @PeterMmm is correct - NetBeans15 just won't work with JDK 8. If upgrading your JDK to 11 or greater solves your problem then consider posting an answer to your own question and accepting it, since answered questions are much more useful to the community.